# Java SimpleDateFormat similar to C#

Tags: c#, java, android, datetime, simpledateformat

I have to get a today Date with this format `{"Date":"2013-09-11T14:47:57.8895887+02:00"}`.
This is because my Json Service is studied for Windows Phone and C# code.

I tried with this method:

```
public static Date getTodayDate() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ:Z");
    Date date = new Date();
    String dateString = dateFormat.format(date);
    Date today = parseFromNormalStringToDate(dateString);
    return today;
}
```

but I get this return

> 2013-09-16T11:47:55.235+0200:+0200;

thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you rather wanna use `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"`

Comment: @olydis eclipse said that "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things to be changed here. First the format.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX"); // This should work for you. Though I must say 6 "S" is not done. You won't get milliseconds for 6 precisions.
Date date = new Date();
String dateString = dateFormat.format(date); // You need to use "dateString" for your JSON
```

And the second thing, the formatted date is the which you need to put in your JSON and not parse it back to `Date`. But `Date` doesn't have a formatting option. You can only get a String representation of the Date in the format you need using SDF.

**Ex:-**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX");
    Date date = new Date();
    String dateString = dateFormat.format(date); // You need to use "dateString" for your JSON
    System.out.println(dateString); // Output
}
```

and the output for this is

> 2013-09-16T15:39:16.000257+05:30

6 digit precision in milliseconds is not possible. If you see the docs of SDF in Java 7, you can find this:-

[image]

The highlighted example is the one you need, but with 6 milliseconds precision, which is not possible. Thus, you can use 6 **S** but it will just add 3 leading zeroes before the actual 3 millisecond digits! This is the only workaround possible in your case!

**Edit:-**

The [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) of Android does not contain `X`. It provides `Z` instead. Therefore your new format string will be

> yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZZZZ

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZZZZ"); // For Android
```

Comment: thanks but.... same error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'" :(

Comment: @Pikkio- You seem to be using Java 6. `X` was introduced in the SDF from Java 7.

Comment: Check these docs. [Java7 SDF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and [Java6 SDF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Sorry I need to re-open this post... I update to Java 7 but when I put 'X' eclipse goes in error. I thought the problem is that the java compiler is 1.6 but whenj I try to change it to 1.7, here the message :

"Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties."

Comment: [link](http://i42.tinypic.com/a4bt4i.png)
[link](http://i42.tinypic.com/2zoy8au.png)

Comment: @Pikkio - Look at the edit in my answer. The last part tells that android doesn't support `X`. It provides `Z` instead of that, and to get the timezone format needed by you, you need to use 5 **Z**! Hope this solves your problem! :)

Comment: I tried with this format:"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZZZZZ"

but the output I read is 
`2013-09-17T14:06:11.000915+0200` :( :( :( 

I think I will never solve it.

Comment: Keep trying with varying no. of Zs! 3, 4 5.. one of that will work!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the "Z:Z" Try "X" this instead :

```
public static Date getTodayDate() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
    Date date = new Date();
    String dateString = dateFormat.format(date);
    Date today = parseFromNormalStringToDate(dateString);
    return today;
}
```

Comment: eclipse said that "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'"

Comment: and how about the 7 numeric characters after seconds?? I thought they are millisecond but I read that in Java we can obtain only 3 milliseconds number :( I m a bit confused

Comment: You need Java 7 to use 'X', see also @R.J answer

Comment: Sorry for the 7 seconds, I didn't see that